# Вопрос с final полем

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Я понял, что final поле нужно инициализировать сразу.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final EntityManagerFactory emf; //ругается

  static{
    try{
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.kudaibergen.restapp");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Initial EntityManagerFactory failed: " + e);
    }
  }

  public static EntityManagerFactory getEmf(){
    return emf;
  }
}
```

Я не понял, почему [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/29694/) это работает? Статья старая, 2008г. Раньше в Java так можно было?

Answer (score 0):

В случае если при инициализации вылетит исключение, то поле останется неинициализированным, для решения стоит сделать ещё что-то вроде `throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);`, тип исключения можно поменять, главное чтобы он был `Uncheked`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, не обратил внимания на бросаемое исключение внизу. Думал не важно). Скажите, в статье бросается тип Error это нормально? Можно так делать?